# How to build a graph using the wikipedia API?

Tags: graph, tree, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I would like to create a graph of the whole Java ecosystem.

I would like to start from the Java Wikipedia article and, from there, follow every connection that deals with the Java programming language, its frameworks, spin-offs, etc.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's possible if you specify what you mean by ramifications. Do you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What information? Maybe include an example?

Comment: I would like to create a graph of the whole Java ecosystem. I would like to get to the Java wikipedia article and, from there, follow every connection that deals with the Java programming language. Its frameworks, spin-offs, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow every link from the article *Java (software platform)*, you can do that using the API. But it also links to some general articles (like *Garbage collection (computer science)*) and some articles that are not about Java (like *C (programming language)*). And those examples are just from the lead section of the article.

What you could do instead is to use the API to walk through [*Category:Java platform*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aJava_platform) and all its subcategories. This should get you all articles about Java and directly related topics.

For example, to get all the pages directly in that category, you can use query like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Java_platform&cmlimit=max